# How to set TCP/IP and DNS settings for individual Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, dns, ip, wifi-configuration

I'd like to have different IP and DNS settings for different Wi-Fi networks. How can I do this in Windows 10?

Comment: You will have to rely on the networks DHCP service in order to do this for more than two networks. One effective alternative is to use a different NIC for each network, at which point you can specify a static IP, DNS server address, and a connection-specific DNS search suffix. Perhaps your best bet is to write powershell scripts that set your NIC information, so you can run the `coffeeshop1.ps` script at the coffee shop, or run `library.ps` when you are at the library.

Comment: PS scripting for network adapters: http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/01/31/using-powershell-to-get-or-set-networkadapterconfiguration-view-and-change-network-settings-including-dhcp-dns-ip-address-and-more-dynamic-and-static-step-by-step.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically but you could script it so you choose which script (or write a dynamic script with various "if" statements) to run and set your TCP/IP/DNS settings via the script.

Alternatively, depending on your networks you could use the "Alternate configuration" tab in the network adapter settings window:

[image]

I'm not a Windows 10 user but I cannot envisage this tab being removed as it's regularly used by people who swap between work and home where the work network may use specific TCP/IP settings... this provides seamless transition between network settings but only works for two configurations...